# How to get a certain value's column name in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this

```
uid|store_1_@_A|store_2_%_7_B|store_3_&_9_C
---------------------------------------
1  |3          |4            |5
2  |20         |1            |9
3  |4          |88           |49
```

I want to form a new table like this:

```
uid|store_1_@_A|store_2_%_7_B|store_3_&_9_C|favorite_store
------------------------------------------------------
1  |3          |4            |5            |C
2  |20         |1            |9            |A
3  |4          |88           |49           |B
```

`favorite_store` is a new variable. For every uid, check the value of three stores, and find one with the highest value, e.g: uid =1, the max value = 5, belongs to store_3_&_9_C, so `favorite_store = C`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'uid':[1,2,3],
                   'store_1_@_A':[3,20,4],
                   'store_2_%_7_B':[4,1,88],
                   'store_3_&_9_C':[5,9,49]})
```

I used `df.iloc[0].max()` to get the max value of first row but I don't know how to proceed. 
In case of how to get the last character in store's name, i was thinking using the last '_' . Such as `re.findall('[^\_]+$', 're.findall('[^\_]+$', 'store_3_A')[0]')[0]` may work.

Comment: So in the third row, favorite store is 88? You probably meant 2

Comment: @AmiTavory yes, i made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['favorite_store'] = df.T.idxmax()                                                                                                                                                

In [5248]: df                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[5248]: 
   uid  store_1  store_2  store_3 favorite_store
0    1        3        4        5        store_3
1    2       20        1        9        store_1
2    3        4       88       49        store_2

or

df['favorite_store'] = df.T.idxmax().str.extract(r'store_(\d+)')                                                                                                                    

In [5266]: df                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[5266]: 
   uid  store_1  store_2  store_3 favorite_store
0    1        3        4        5              3
1    2       20        1        9              1
2    3        4       88       49              2
```

Comment: ```df['favorite_store'] = df.T.idxmax().str.extract(r'store_(\d+)') ``` is really a cleaner way. but in fact i just simplify the situation. In really case, the store's name is like ```store_1_A``` , then how can i modify ```r'store_(\d+)'``` to get A?

Comment: @bulala use r'store_(.*$)' that should grab everything after 'store_' to the end of the line

Comment: yes, i got str like '3_C', i am still working on it.  There are must be some ways to find the last '-' and then get everything after the last '_'

Comment: @bulala I created this for your to test: https://regex101.com/r/u98TVd/1  You can change it around and hit save regex on the left and send me what your working on that may not match and i could take a look at it.

Comment: i tested ```[^\_]+$```,  it seems worked. ```re.findall('[^\_]+$', 'store_3_A')[0]``` i can get A from this. but i don't know how to modify your code to fit it.

Comment: @bulala you just want the A and not the 3? Or do you want 3A or 3_A. I just need a little help understanding and i will update the regex

Comment: oh, i get your point. I want everything that after the last '-' in the store name. I have updated my post. I was my bad for just not thinking throughly.

Comment: what i  want is actually "A"

Comment: Like this: https://regex101.com/r/u98TVd/2  it will only match the green

Answer (score 2):

Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df['favorite_store'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: i ran the code and got the error:unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str. ```df.idxmax(axis=1)``` is not an int type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'uid':[1,2,3],
               'store_1':[3,20,4],
               'store_2':[4,1,88],
               'store_3':[5,9,49]})

fav_full = (df.idxmax(axis=1))
fav_value = []
for ele in fav_full:
    fav_value.append(ele[6:])
df['Favourite column'] = (fav_value)
print (df)
```

There must be a cleaner way to do this. But this will work if all your 'store' headers are in the format: store_x

Comment: i got store names like 'store_1' instead of 1

Comment: I have made certain changes in the code. Try again now.

Comment: If it worked for you then consider giving my answer a green tick. Cheers!